# How to get the current Title of a button in Swift?

Tags: swift

*What am I doing wrong?*

*I get this error:*

**let letterString = sender.title(for: .normal)!**  // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

*when I tried to get the title of a button in swift like below:*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // My IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var treeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var correctWordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    // My Outlet Collection
    @IBOutlet var letterButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        // Begin the round.
        newRound()
        
    }
    
    var listOfWords = ["estufa", "nevera", "computadora", "empanada", "chuleta", "camarones", "brincar", "correr", "caminar", "tigre", "jirafa", "mono", "kisseemmee", "Tampa", "Orlando"]
    let incorrectMovesAllowed = 7
    let totalWins = 0
    let totalLosses = 0
    
    
    // My IBActions
    @IBAction func letterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isEnabled = false


        let letterString = sender.title(for: .normal)!  // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


        let letter = Character(letterString.lowercased())
        currentGame.playerGuessed(letter: letter)
        updateUI()
    }
    
    var currentGame: Game!
    
    func newRound() {
        let newWord = listOfWords.removeFirst()
        currentGame = Game(word: newWord, incorrectMovesRemaining: incorrectMovesAllowed, guessedLetters: [])
        updateUI()
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses: \(totalLosses)"
        treeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
    }
}
```

// Game.swift file code:

```
import Foundation

struct Game {
    var word: String
    var incorrectMovesRemaining: Int
    var guessedLetters: [Character]
    
    mutating func playerGuessed(letter: Character) {
        guessedLetters.append(letter)
        if !word.contains(letter) {
            incorrectMovesRemaining -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

*I'm a newbie.  This is my first program.  I appreciate if you code the solution.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the title of the `UIButton` using `titleLabel` property. Check the below code.

```
sender.titleLabel?.text
```

As the above code returns optional, you can use optional chain to safely get the string

```
if let titleLabel = sender.titleLabel {
    let title = titleLabel.text
}
```

**OR**

You can also use the `currentTitle` property as below.

```
sender.currentTitle
```

Comment: The property **currentTitle** is also optional, so you will need to check its value before usage, like the previous example, or just simply adding the **!** operator at the end of the property.

sender.currentTitle!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
sender.titleLabel.text